# I have an EF query that is very very slow. How can I debug this?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following classes that are backed up by EF6 and the SQL Server 2012 database. I have about 500 records in the question table, 250 in the problem table, and 20 in the subtopic table:

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int ProblemId { get; set; }
    public int QuestionStatusId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public DateTime AssignedDate { get; set; }
    public int QuestionTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Problem Problem { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionStatus QuestionStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }
}
public class Problem
{
    public Problem()
    {
        this.Questions = new List<Question>();
    }
    public int ProblemId { get; set; }
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual SubTopic SubTopic { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
public partial class SubTopic
{
    public SubTopic()
    {;
        this.Problems = new List<Problem>();
    }
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Problem> Problems { get; set; }
    public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }
}
```

I set up the following maps:

```
    public ProblemMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ProblemId);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.SubTopic)
            .WithMany(t => t.Problems)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.SubTopicId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
    public QuestionMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.QuestionId);
        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Problem)
            .WithMany(t => t.Questions)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProblemId);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.QuestionStatus)
            .WithMany(t => t.Questions)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.QuestionStatusId);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.QuestionType)
            .WithMany(t => t.Questions)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.QuestionTypeId);
    }
    public SubTopicMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.SubTopicId);
        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Topic)
            .WithMany(t => t.SubTopics)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.TopicId);
    }
```

I am trying to do a query on these that looks like this:

```
IList<Question> questions;
questions = _questionsRepository
    .GetAll()
    .Where(q => q.Problem.SubTopic.TopicId == topicId || topicId == 0)
    .Where(q => q.QuestionStatusId == questionStatusId || questionStatusId == 0)
    .Where(q => q.AssignedTo == assignedTo || assignedTo == "0")
    .Where(q => q.ModifiedBy == modifiedBy || modifiedBy == "0")
    .Include(q => q.Problem)
    .Include(q => q.Answers)
    .ToList();
```

The problem is that the query starts but never seems to return. Is there something I am doing wrong?  Is there a way that I can find out what kind of query it is trying to execute against the database?

Could it be the following that is making things run slow:

```
    q.Problem.SubTopic.TopicId == topicId
```

Here is the repository GetAll()

```
    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using tools like [Entity Profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf)? I have tried it with one of my queries and is very helpful. I am sure there are other tools too.

Comment: Can you show us the code of your repository (+ `GetAll()`)? You should specify `Include()` before the `Where()`. Moreover check your generated SQL query while debugging, check it, and test it directly in SQL Server

Comment: @glautrou - I have included the GetAll() in the questions. I didn't know that I should do the Include() before the Where() I have a few ideas now on things to check. Hope something can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Linq to Entity query visualizer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/99468ece-689b-481c-868c-19e00e0a4e69)

It's a free extension for Visual Studio. Description:

> View Native SQL (MS SQL, DB2, Oracle, etc) of LInQ to entities ObjectQuery while debugging in Visual Studio 2008/2010/. Also view Lambda expression, edit Query parameters, view DB Connection info, view query results, and export results to MS Excel(No MS Excel required)

You can then copy the query and paste it in SQL Server if you need to.

You can also use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). This application lets you write an test LINQ expressions targeted to different database backends and different flavors of LINQ: LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities, LINQ to Objects...

And finally, the [free version of DevArt LINQ Insight (express versions)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/269e6da9-7f4d-4650-a327-c70b359dcfe0?SRC=Featured). It's also a VS extension.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. Might be just what I am looking for.

Comment: Added 2 extra links to different LINQ tools. I have not tested the first one with EF6 but with EF5.

Comment: WARNING: Read the reviews for the second link. Apparently it's a 30day trial and takes out some features after that. Not "quite" free.

Comment: @statue: Read the link text: "The free version of DevArt LINQ Insight (Express version)" The express version is free, as is. What you've seen is that the download of the express version includes a trial of 30 days of the fulll version. Of course, the full can do more things than the express: display returned data and profile the queries: http://www.devart.com/linqinsight/editions.html. However, the express is still veryuseful without this functionality.

Comment: I read that, hence "and takes out some features after that." Just a warning!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this query works at all. You do not have a joins between question and problem as well as problem and subtopic. If you rewrite the query with joins, I see no reason for it to not perform properly.

Try something like this:

```
from q in db.Questions
join p in db.Problems on q.ProblemId equals p.ProblemId
join s in db.SubTopics on s.SubTopicId equals p.SubTopicId
where q.QuestionStatusId == questionStatusId &&
q.AssignedTo == assignedTo
q.ModifiedBy == modifiedBy
s.TopicId == topicId
select q
```

In order to debug I use SQL Profiler. Once you have the query from SQL Profiler, you can use the Database Engine Tuning Advisor to see if you are missing indexes on your DB.